# detecting hijacked code with call outs

Tags: php, magento

I have a low traffic magento install and all of a sudden it is running really slow. I blocked RIPE ip blocks using ip tables and now the site won't load after I perform a search for something using the search box in magento. Also the admin panel runs very slow.  I am trying to make sure there wasn't any malicious code injected. I am trying to detect whether there is a call out to another server that when blocked keeps my site from loading. Is this possible to detect and how so?

Is it possible for someone to hijack a magento install this way?

Comment: Could be, But slowness may depends upon your server. What is the server configuration? Also it might be because you have disabled the magento cache from backend. Which version of magento it is?

Comment: I have a dedicate dual proc xeon server with two ssd in raid. Only one of several sites is running slow all of a sudden. The server itself is not running slow. How do I check if there are call outs to another ip? I was thinking of transferring the code over to a server at home that is not on an external network, and checking ip address call outs right before when it hangs. I am getting too many attacks from RIPE networks and any help in resolving this would be appreciated.